# Suggestions for hosted log server?

Tags: logging, log4net, nlog

I'm looking for recommendations for a hosted service to collect logging information from client applications. The service would preferably be a high-availability service using a cloud infrastructure or something equivalent.

I'd like to be able to direct some logging information from my .NET client application (using a logging framework like Log4Net or NLog) to this logging server and then access the log data via a web interface of some kind. Obviously the more features on the web interface for analyzing the log data, the better. Writing a simple service myself to do this wouldn't be that hard, but I'd rather just pay a reasonable monthly fee for someone else to maintain and improve it. The service

I found a couple of options including

1. Gibraltor Hub @ http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com
2. LogVerse @ http://www.logverse.com/
3. LogFaces (not hosted) @ http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/

Surely there must be many of these sorts of services out there, but I haven't figured out the right search terms to find them. Any recommendations for services you've used? Thanks!

Comment: As the comments below discuss, it's possible to use some of the web analytics sites (and possibly the Silverlight Analytics Framework) to accomplish something similar and there are lots of those. But other than the 3 logging sites I listed above, I haven't found other real options. I'm sure they must exist out there under some keywords I haven't thought of yet. On the other hand it might be a great Azure project. <grin> Are you looking for something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I tried Loggly, but found the user interface to be very confusing and it basically seemed to not work some of the time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of the "not work some of the time" thing.

Answer (score 0):

The folks at preemptive (dotfuscator) also provide similar services, mostly around usage analysis. They're .Net specific though. I've never used their product so I can't say whether they're good or not. Here's a link to their product: http://www.preemptive.com/products/runtime-intelligence/overview

Comment: Hmmmm. That's more like Google Analytics. I suppose that for some usage analysis purposes it would work. But not really for error log purposes. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly give [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com) a try. I've found MongoDB is really great for massive data sets and MapReduce jobs.